# N2CMS: restricting the number of ContentItems of a certain type below another ContentItem

Tags: n2cms, n2

I'm using N2CMS, and I have two classes that inherit from ContentItem - say HomePage and NewsPage. NewsPage is set to only appear under HomePage (using the RestrictParents attribute):

```
[RestrictParents(typeof(HomePage))]
```

Can I make it so there is a maximum number of NewsPages (in this case 1) below the home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you can use the

```
[RestrictCardinality]
```

attribute. In the example I gave in the question, you would use

```
[RestrictCardinality(ComparableType=typeof(NewsPart), MaximumCount=1)]
```